# Java: How to add variable in a loop together, multiple times

Tags: java, loops, variables, while-loop

```
public class R {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;

      int j = 0;
      int distance = 0;

      while (trials>j) {
          j = j + 1;
          int i = -1;
          double counter = 1.0 * distance;
          double sum = (distance + counter); 
          while (i<=n) {
              i = i + 1;
              if (i == n) {
              distance = ((x*x) + (y*y));
              }
              if (i<n) {   
                  int random = (int )(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
                  if (random == 1) x = x + 1;
                  if (random == 2) y = y + 1; 
                  if (random == 3) x = x - 1;
                  if (random == 4) y = y - 1;
              }
          }        
      }
      double average= (sum)/(trials);
      System.out.println("mean " + "squared " + "distance " + "= " + average);

  }
}
```

Hey guys I'm wondering how it's possible to compute a value within a loop, and then every single time the loop finishes (and the value in computed) to average them together. I can't wrap my head around the concept and I tried doing it in the code above but I can't quite figure it out.

As you can see there are two while loops, and inside one of them a random value (distance) is computed. So essentially I need to average the distances together, but I can't imagine how it's possible to add the distances that are computed each time together into one number. Let's say the loop goes through one time and outputs a singular distance, how would I go about adding a new distance (for the new loop) together with the old one, and then keep doing that for each trial?

Comment: Have a variable to hold a cumulative sum and another for a counter. Then just calculate the average after each loop.

Comment: Hi there, are you asking for conceptual help on such a problem or specific help on how to go about calculating the average of distances for a number of trails?

Comment: Yeah conceptual help I guess. I just fixed my code based on the first comment and thought I figured it out, but it seems that java has an issue with my average calculation using a variable that is declared inside the loops, and using it outside of the loops.

Comment: Are you trying to investigate the random walk theory over two dimensions? In that case, shouldn't the movement be in terms of a radius of 1 and a random angle? What you are doing here is moving by a radius of 1 and an angle that is either 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to divide the total distance per trials.

```
public class R {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;

      int j = 0;
      int distance = 0, distance_total = 0;

      while (trials>j) {
          j = j + 1;
          int i = -1;
          distance = 0;
          while (i<=n) {
              i = i + 1;
              if (i == n) {
              distance += ((x*x) + (y*y));
              }
              if (i<n) {   
                  int random = (int )(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
                  if (random == 1) x = x + 1;
                  if (random == 2) y = y + 1; 
                  if (random == 3) x = x - 1;
                  if (random == 4) y = y - 1;
              }
          }        
          distance_total += distance;
      }
      System.out.println(distance_total/j);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much man. I don't know why I struggled so much trying to think about this. I editted the code again and I think it works completely.

Comment: Glad to help. If you have any questions on what i changed in your code, just ask.